# Why does "unsigned int" + "unsigned int" return an "unsigned int"?

Tags: c++, types

I believe that when you add two `unsigned int` values together, the returned value's data type will be an `unsigned int`.

But the addition of two `unsigned int` values may return a value that is larger than an `unsigned int`.

So why does `unsigned int` + `unsigned int` return an `unsigned int` and not some other larger data type?

Comment: And if you add those together you get another larger data type? So 100 lines into your program you run out of memory?

Comment: If you need to handle overflow, you have to program that into your code.

Comment: `unsigned int` + `unsigned int` can never be greater than `unsigned int` since all math done on it is done modulo `2^unsigned int bits`

Comment: When you do `int + int` it can also overflow. Should that return say `long long int`?

Comment: _So why does `unsigned` + `unsigned` return an `unsigned`?_ That's how it is defined in the language. The reason is probably that the underlying H/W may do it this way. Though, the CPU may have a carry flag to store an overflow but this is not reflected in C++.

Comment: This is just "integer overflow".  Read about it here:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow

Comment: @Scheff - the hardware doesn't have to "store an overflow" when adding unsigned variables.   The way the circuitry works (for example, in a machine register), the truncation happens automatically, by simply discarding the additional bits (which is why `unsigned` operations use modulo arithmetic).

Comment: @Peter I know, I walk on thin ice as having written asm for 8086 and 6502 only (and that's decades ago). While 8086 has two addition commands (ADC and ADD where one considers carry and the other not), 6502 has only one (ADC). For the latter, the carry flag has to be cleared if it should not be considered. However, I stay for the _That's how it is defined in the language._ ;-)

Comment: @ruohola:  Are you changing from `unsigned` to `signed`?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I don't get the question.

Comment: A `long long int` is a *signed* quantity (usually the highest bit is the sign bit).  An `unsigned int` is an *unsigned* quantity (cannot represent negative numbers).  So, the OP's `unsigned int` + `unsigned int` result should be `unsigned long` or `unsigned long long`.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Yes I know all of that. That's why I *jokingly* asked if adding two `int`s should also make a `long long`...

Answer (score 2):

This would have truly evil consequences:

Would you *really* want 1 + 1 to be a `long` type? And `(1 + 1) + (1 + 1)` would become a `long long` type? It would wreak havoc with the type system.

It's also possible, for example, that `short`, `int`, `long`, and `long long` are all the same size, and similarly for the `unsigned` versions.

So the implicit type conversion rules as they stand are probably the best solution.

You could always force the issue with something like

```
0UL + "unsigned int" + "unsigned int"
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's imagine that we have a language where adding two integers results in a bigger type. So, adding two 32 bit numbers results in a 64 bit number. What would happen in expression the following expression?

```
auto x = a + b + c + d + e + f + g;
```

`a + b` is 64 bits. `a + b + c` is 128 bits. `a + b + c + d` is 256 bits... This becomes unmanageable very fast. Most processors don't support operations with so wide operands.

Comment: I don't remember the name, but there is a C++ library that keeps track of the maximum size of numbers with template arguments. And it does not become unmanageable very fast because 7 numbers with 32 bits added can only need up to 35 bits. And you can use a 64 bit number to hold the 35 bits. It can become unmanageable somewhat fast though, depending on the operations.

Comment: @nwp fair enough. Tracking the number of max potential bits  through the expression rather than only the type of the expression would allow keep some expressions such as the example maintainable. Have you seen that library used in production?

Comment: I can't find it anymore. I remember one of the guests of cppcast talking about it. But even if I did find it I would see "used in production" as an irrelevant property.

Comment: Not being used in production anywhere in the world is a massive signal, not an irrelevant property.

Comment: Anyway that's not the point. Such a library is probably used in production, but it is a specialized library, tackling large integers for specific usage. Using it for regular arithmetic would incur a huge performance penalty.

Answer (score 2):

The type of a varaible does not only determine the range of values it can hold, but sloppy speaking, also how the operations are realized. If you add two `unsigned` values you get an `unsigned` result. If you want a different type as result (eg `long unsigned`) you could cast:

```
unsigned x = 42;
unsigned y = 42;
long unsigned z = static_cast<long unsigned>(x) + static_cast<long unsigned>(y);
```

Actually the real reason is: It is defined like that. In particular unsigned overflow is well defined in C++ to wrap around and using a wider type for the result of `unsigned` operators would break that behaviour.

As a contrived example, consider this loop:

```
for (unsigned i = i0; i != 0; ++i) {}
```

Note the condition! Lets assume `i0 > 0`, then it can only ever be false when incrementing the maximum value of `unsigned` results in `0`. This code is obfuscated and should probably make you raise an eyebrow or two in a code-review, though it is perfectly legal. Making the result type adjust depending on the value of the result, or choosing the result type such that overflow cannot happen would break this behaviour.

Answer (score -3):

Because a variable + a same type variable can be only equal to that type variable ,
(well in some cases it will but not in your case)

example:

int + int = int a int plus another int cannot be equal to a float because it dont have the properties of a float.
I hope this answers your question bye!

Comment: Nice in theory, but `char + char` and `short + short` both get promoted to `int` (possibly `unsigned int` for a `char` on some platforms).

Comment: in general for some types `T` and `S`, `T() + S()` can result in any type, the result of `operator+` being the exact same type is maybe even the exception

Comment: you are right BUT in my example a say an a + a = a not that an a + b = a plus @elijay you are right and i apologize